# How to add fixed delay for each Task in monix without building up delay

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, monix

I'm consuming messages from kafka using monix.

I want to process the message 10 sec after the message is read from the topic.

This delay of 10 sec minute shouldn't block reading more messages.

I've tried to test this behaviour using the following code using the Task.delayExecution to delay by 10 sec

I've also tried `Observable.delayOnExecution` and `Observable.delayOnNext`

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.reactive.Observable

object TestApp extends App {
  import java.util.Date
  case class SomeClass(
                        value: Int, consumingDate: Date,
                        handlerExecutionDate: Date = null
                      )
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent.Await
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

  val res = Observable.fromIterable((1 to 100).map(i => SomeClass(value = i, consumingDate = new Date)))
    .mapEval(i =>
      Task.delay(
        SomeClass(
          value = i.value,
          consumingDate = i.consumingDate
        )
      ).delayExecution(10 seconds)
    )
    .foreachL{ x =>
      val r = SomeClass(
        x.value,
        x.consumingDate,
        new Date()
      )
      println(r)
    }.runToFuture
  Await.result(res, 100.seconds)
}
```

But the above code adds up delay for each message. 1st message delays by 10 sec, but 2nd delays by 20 sec, 3rd by 30 sec and so on.

Is it possible to do something like this using monix?

I'm considering other alternatives to monix based solution, like using an In-memory Queue. The consumer will keep pushing to the Queue until it's limit is reached and then.

**Update :**

I've found a solution using `Task.eval(<current_time>).restartUntil(<condition>)`

Adding the code for that below.

```
package com.agoda.cusco.campaign.data.collector.consumer

import monix.eval.Task
import monix.reactive.Observable

object TestApp extends App {
  import java.util.Date
  case class SomeClass(
                        value: Int, consumingDate: Date,
                        handlerExecutionDate: Date = null
                      )
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent.Await
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

  val res = Observable.fromIterable((1 to 100).map(i => SomeClass(value = i, consumingDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis + i*100))))
    .mapEval(message =>
      Task.eval(new Date()).restartUntil(currentTime => (currentTime.getSeconds - message.consumingDate.getSeconds) > 10).map(_ => message)
    )
    .foreachL{ x =>
      val r = SomeClass(
        x.value,
        x.consumingDate,
        new Date()
      )
      println(r)
    }.runToFuture
  Await.result(res, 100.seconds)
}
```

I'm not completely sure if it's the ideal solution as it seems to be doing active CPU computation to make it work.

Would like to check if there are any better alternatives.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I tried to run your code and it printed lines with date and time each 10 seconds, are you sure what you have such increasing delays?

Comment: Yeah, you're right that the difference printed is actually 10 sec. But it is still increasing delays as the events/messages are all generated at the same time in `Observable.fromIterable(1 to 100)` but the print of each message happens with 10 sec delay. I'll update the code such that it represents the issue more clearly.

Comment: If its for technical reasons, sounds like a design issue. If its a product requirement, then I guess this is a solution.
Queuing up in memory from kafka is often an anti pattern. Each partition is a queue. A consumer should pull what it can consume. Otherwise need to write logic to handle buffer overruns, lose in memory messages when the instance crashes or reboots. You could get over losing messages with manual offset commits. Dropping messages on buffer overrun is often needed for real time processing, where you have to drop messages when processing cant keep up with the incoming rate.